boldmath and eulervm together shrink the equal sign
I just notice that if I use eulervm together with \boldmath, then the equal sign shrinks.  Here is a minimal working example:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}
\boldmath

\begin{align*}
  A & \le B
  \\
    & =   C
\end{align*}

\end{document}

This issue disappears if I comment out either \boldmath or \usepackage{eulervm}.  But I need both; how can I get back the regular equal sign?
THANKS!

You should also notice that the \le looks different. It seems that enabling \boldmath uses LaTeX's default symbols as a fallback since Euler-VM doesn't provide bold versions of them. How about using \boldsymbol{...}, or better yet, \bm{...} from the bm package, for each symbol you want to have bold instead?

@Gargantuar \bm and \boldsymbol use the font setup from \boldmath, that's how they know which bold fonts to use, so if \boldmath does not provide suitable fonts they will not help

Thanks @gargantuar.  For whatever reasons I need to bold all the symbols, which is why I put \boldmath at the start of the document.  As a substitute/hack, is there a way to just override the equal sign AND \neq sign?

It's a bug in the eufb10 font that's used for building the virtual font zeusb10. The glyph is wrongly designed. The \leq symbol is taken from msam10 for the medium version (the one used for \leqslant, but this font has no boldface companion, so zeusb10 takes it from cmbsy10 and it's the standard \leq.
